# Nested views in Ionic Tabs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have an application using the Ionic Tabs template as so:

```
 // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
   .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
     abstract: true,
     templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html',
  })

   // Each tab has its own nav history stack:
   .state('tab.trips', {
     url: '/trips',
     views: {
       'tab-trips': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/trips.html',
          controller: 'TripsCtrl',
        }
      }
    })

.state('tab.trip-detail', {
    url: '/trips/:tripId',
    views: {
      'tab-trips': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/trip-detail.html',
        controller: 'DestinationCtrl',
      }
    }
  })
```

Here we have the abstract state 'tab', then the first master view in 'tab.trips' and its detail view 'tab.trip-detail'.

Inside the detail view 'tab.trip-detail' I want to be able to display different templates for different states in this view.

Not sure how to set up the states for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can do that. I suggest you to use `ng-include`:

Sample of codes you may refer:

```
<ion-pane>
    <ion-tabs>
        <ion-tab title="Tab 1"...>
            <ion-view>
                <div ng-include src="'templates/tab1.html'"></div> <!-- You can manipulate this source -->
            </ion-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="Tab 2"... >
            <ion-view>
                <div ng-include src="'templates/tab2.html'"></div> <!-- You can manipulate this source -->
            </ion-view>
        </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-pane>
```

Comment: Gave the green tick - used part of this approach where I used the divs ng-include directive to achieve my what I needed. Cheers